# Change Default theme by module

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I am very beginner in drupal.
I want to change the theme every day of week for users.
for example in saturday show theme 'garland', on sunday show theme 'seven' and so on.
how can I implement it. 
I have searched a lot but I found nothing especial.
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

sounds like you are looking for the [themekey](https://www.drupal.org/project/themekey) module!?

> ThemeKey allows you to define simple or sophisticated theme-switching rules which allow automatic selection of a theme depending on current path, taxonomy terms, language, node-type, and many, many other properties.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to change your frontend theme is to set it in your sites/default/settings.php:

```
    if(date("w")==0)
$conf['theme_default'] = 'seven';
else if(date("w")==1)
$conf['theme_default'] = 'garland';
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve it by implementing [hook_custom_theme](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_custom_theme/7)

You can figure out what active theme key is by calling:

```
global $theme_key
```

inside your hook implementation. Of course every theme that you want to use should be enabled.